# Image view reference in adapter using volley android

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-volley

Hi suppose i am loading image in imageview using volley in adapter. if image loading completed then onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean arg1) fn will be called. my problem is that whether i will get the correct reference of the corresponding image view which is loaded inside onResponse ??
i need to change the scale type of image view after image is loaded.

```
 netImageLoader.get(thumbUrl, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e("Error", "Image Load Error: " + error.getMessage());
                holder.postImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
                holder.postImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.placeholder_video_image);
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean arg1) {
                if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                    // load image into imageview
                   holder.postImage.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    holder.postImage.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Show your code what you have tried?

Comment: hi @ρяσѕρєяK , thanks for the reply.added code in question please check.